How should I choose a good research project group?
I have an opprotunity to join one of several research groups during my undergraduate (physics) degree, in a different university. I therefore do not know the people nor the professors very well.
I'm trying to choose between the research groups. I've met and spoken with 3 professors who lead 3 different research groups. They all truely seemed genuine and very helpful. We discussed the nature of the groups, some ideas I could work on, etc.
They all work in different subjects (astrophysics, complex systems, optics), all of which I know next to nothing about, other than standard science-education type of content.
I also felt a connection with them of varying degrees. I 'spoke the language' of the astrophysics and complex systems researchers more, while with the optics researcher, I didn't get his explainations very well. The Comp Systems researcher is known to be a good teacher.
However, in terms of acclaim, from Google Scholar it looks like the optics researcher is by far the most accomplished (his h-index indicates this too), with the atro researcher a not-so-close second and the complex systems guy in last place.
The optics researcher was very very kind and gave me tips, but again, I really didn't get his explainations very well, and I know next to nothing about the field, while the other researchers managed to give me a decent view of what they were doing.
How could one, in a situation like this, try to choose? I feel like I really do not know enough to make an informed decision. I'd love to hear guidelines and tips for how to asses this sort of choice, especially when knowledge is limited due to lack of experience in these fields.

Too personal and too many variables. Which would you actually like to do?

Yes that's a fair criticism, I was contemplating making it a bit less specific but I decided the question itself is general enough. As for which I'd like to do, it might be the complex systems research. I'm just don't know how much the status of the researcher is something I should consider, if I want to show this research off on my resume for example.

It seems too early to worry about things like h-index and other status indicators. You want someone who can work with you, not just write a bunch of papers. More important, you want something that interests you. Otherwise it is hard to succeed.

And, as a limited temporary situation it really doesn't matter that much - you will get experience one way or the other...

H-index aside, my advice would be to choose a professor and topic based on:

What you want to learn more about right now:
Choose a topic you're interested in. If you're going to be doing research in a specific area, it can be difficult to stay motivated if you're not particularly interested in what you're studying/researching.

What will be useful for you in the future:
Choose something to create a strong knowledge or skill base for later learning. Reflect on the things you want to learn whether that's the scientific knowledge you wish to gain, coding skills, writing skills, experimentation, etc. Especially if you want to go to grad school, developing these skills early on can be a great advantage, both for your academic growth and your CV.

Fit with the professor:
At the undergraduate level, it's unlikely that you will be expected to be very independent. As a result, you may be quite reliant on the professor you work with (which can be a good thing because it will allow you to learn a great deal from them). My advice would be to choose the professor with whom you have the best rapport, who you feel would support your learning best, whose explanations you understand, and feel most comfortable asking questions to.


Best of luck!
